# Azure Api Management log user accessed api

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management

Is there any rest api that can be used to fetch api access detail for a user. To know how many times a user accessed a api and how many success or failure request were there. i am not able to use log-to-eventhub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @*MayankBargali-MSFT*'s [Q&A answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/926076/how-to-get-the-details-of-who-the-last-user-access.html) to similar kind of issue and posting here to help other community members!

> Azure APIM will do [monitor the APIs published](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-use-azure-monitor) but only listed details are logged as per the [APIManagementGatewayLogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/apimanagementgatewaylogs).

Based on your requirement, leveage the APIM [reporting API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/reports) and refer to [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/howto-use-analytics) for more information on reporting API.

> **To know who the user accessed particular API in APIM recently**, You can call the [List by Request API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/reports/list-by-request?tabs=HTTP) by adding the filter (For example, last 4 days from this day, `apiID`, etc.).
>
> [image]

The above response will provide the details like `apiID`, `timeStamp`, `userID` that helps to find the details.

Still paraphrasing *@MayankBargali-MSFT* from the post linked above:

**To know how many time that user accessed the API**, *use [List by User API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/reports/list-by-user?tabs=HTTP) where it gives the overall result in which we need to filter with the `apiID`, then you can get the API Level count.*

**Point to note here is**:
*Filter might not work for every column. Therefore, you must modify the outcome at your client's end to perform more filtering and obtain the appropriate result. For further information, kindly consult the relevant API document. As long as you don't delete the APIM instance, the data will continue to be maintained permanently.*